# Platform-dependent PHP hashing in Production and Development environments

Tags: php, hash, phpass

I decided to drop md5() as the password-encrypting algorithm when storing user passwords in DB, in favor of [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library.

On the systems using md5, it was no problem to have a Production/Development dyad, as the resulting hash was the same. So, in case I created a test user in either one of them, the same password worked in the other environment.

From what I gather, this is not the same for other types of hashing algorithms, as phpass (or its internal php functions) creates platform-dependent hashes (I'm a hashing/encryption novice).

My question is, how should one approach this situation? Different database in prod/dev? But what if "upstairs" decided that we should move our web application (along with its DB) to another server - wouldn't the hashed passwords be now invalid - as phpass would create *different* hashes for the same (old) passwords?

### Later edit:

Well, I didn't bother to check a dev hash to a production one. Even though they're different, their comparison results in "true", as in "they're quivalent". I thought, if hashes are different, they don't match (like md5).

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that supports PHPass is platform-dependent?

Comment: Uhm.. no. Still, the resulting hash of the *same* string is different in dev (Win XP) and production (Ubuntu).

Comment: It shouldn't be producing a different result on different machines, AFAIK. Encryption could, but you're not *encrypting*, you're *hashing*. Without being able to test otherwise, I would guess your XP machine does not have the same hash libraries available as your Ubuntu machine, so it's using/falling back to a different hashing algorithm. See example 3 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: See [here](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/): *To ensure that the fallbacks will never occur, PHP 5.3.0+ or the Suhosin patch may be used. PHP 5.3.0+ and Suhosin integrate crypt_blowfish into the PHP interpreter such that bcrypt is available for use by PHP scripts even if the host system lacks support for it.*

Comment: And of course this from the same link: *The preferred (most secure) hashing method supported by phpass is the OpenBSD-style Blowfish-based bcrypt, also supported with our public domain crypt_blowfish package (for C applications), and known in PHP as CRYPT_BLOWFISH, with a fallback to BSDI-style extended DES-based hashes, known in PHP as CRYPT_EXT_DES, and a last resort fallback to MD5-based salted and variable iteration count password hashes implemented in phpass itself (also referred to as portable hashes).* So it looks like it tries to use Blowfish if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution to your problem: Always use the latest stable version of PHP. As of 5.3 PHP provides native implementations of `crypt` algorithms and thus isn't platform dependent anymore. Your hashes should thus be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you decided to use the phpass library?  You didn't elaborate on that point, but if you were simply looking for a more secure algorithm than MD5, take a look at [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) coupled with an algorithm like sha512.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, irrelevant. It's not about hash security (altough this has lead me to avoid md5 in the first place), but about *different* hashes of the same string and how to approach this without the password becoming invalid on another system.

Comment: Hash algorithms do not produce different output on different systems.  I don't know anything about phpass, but perhaps it's using a different algorithm on one of your systems because that system does not support the algorithm it used on the original system.

Answer (score 0):

**Tiger algorithms in PHP**

The `Tiger192,4` algorithm is often recommended for hashing, however I've just discovered you can get different hash values on different machines.

> Impossible! (you say)

Well it turns out PHP <5.4 implements `Tiger` with *LSB* first, while PHP 5.4+ implements `Tiger` with *MSB* first.  Which is correct?  I can't say (LSB matches [testtiger](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Ebiham/Reports/Tiger/testresults.html) while MSB matches the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29) examples) but the point is... **don't use `Tiger` if hashes need to be portable or survive a PHP upgrade** (a PHP 5.3->5.4 will break a `Tiger` hashed password table, which has significant maintainability implications).

To test...

```
echo hash("tiger192,3","The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cog")."\n".
     hash("tiger192,3","");
```

*MSB:* (PHP 5.4.5)
`a8f04b0f7201a0d728101c9d26525b31764a3493fcd8458f`
`3293ac630c13f0245f92bbb1766e16167a4e58492dde73f3`

*LSB:* (PHP 5.3.2)
`d7a001720f4bf0a8315b52269d1c10288f45d8fc93344a76`
`24f0130c63ac933216166e76b1bb925ff373de2d49584e7a`

(My solution? Use a different algorithm, *and* embed a known hash test in the unit test code)